# how to include sqlite database in exe.file in python?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, connection, executable

I have created a system that can add, delete, edit records using a SQLite database. so I want to include database into my exe. file to have a one executable file system with a database? is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it is a horrible idea due to unnecessary complexity of maintaining a self-modifying program, especially if you plan to convert this into some form of exe.

Comment: so what is the easiest or the best way that can store a large amount of data? or should I shift into another type of database?